# get length of list per scraped link

Tags: python, web-scraping, linked-list

I am quite new to Python and I need your professional advice.
What I want in the end is, that I get the lenght of the injury_list per player. The players are stored in PlayerLinks

```
playerLinks = ['https://www.transfermarkt.de/Serge Gnabry/verletzungen/spieler/159471',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Jamal Musiala/verletzungen/spieler/580195',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Douglas Costa/verletzungen/spieler/75615',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Joshua Kimmich/verletzungen/spieler/161056',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Alexander Nübel/verletzungen/spieler/195778',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Kingsley Coman/verletzungen/spieler/243714',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Christopher Scott/verletzungen/spieler/503162',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Corentin Tolisso/verletzungen/spieler/190393',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Leon Goretzka/verletzungen/spieler/153084',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Javi Martínez/verletzungen/spieler/44017',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Tiago Dantas/verletzungen/spieler/429987',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Robert Lewandowski/verletzungen/spieler/38253',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Lucas Hernández/verletzungen/spieler/281963',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Josip Stanisic/verletzungen/spieler/483046',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Thomas Müller/verletzungen/spieler/58358',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Benjamin Pavard/verletzungen/spieler/353366',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Bouna Sarr/verletzungen/spieler/190685',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Leroy Sané/verletzungen/spieler/192565',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Manuel Neuer/verletzungen/spieler/17259',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/David Alaba/verletzungen/spieler/59016',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Niklas Süle/verletzungen/spieler/166601',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Tanguy Nianzou/verletzungen/spieler/538996',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Ron-Thorben Hoffmann/verletzungen/spieler/317444',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Jérôme Boateng/verletzungen/spieler/26485',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Alphonso Davies/verletzungen/spieler/424204',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Eric Maxim Choupo-Moting/verletzungen/spieler/45660',
 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/Marc Roca/verletzungen/spieler/336869']
```

```
injury_list = []
name_list = []
```

With the code below I get a list of all injuries of all playersLinks.
However, the lists are not from equal size. And I need the name of each player next to the injuries of that specific player.

I tried the following:
However, the lenght of injury_list is a random numebr then and not the number per player.
How do I get instead the lenght of the injury_list by player?
In order that I have the correct names next to the injuries.

```
for p in range(len(playerLinks)):
    page = playerLinks[p]
    response = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    print(response.status_code)
    injury_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(injury_data, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id="yw1")
    injurytypes = table.select("td[class='hauptlink']")
    
        
    for j in range(len(injurytypes)):
            all_injuries = [injury.text for injury in injurytypes]
            injury_list.extend(all_injuries)

    image = soup.find("div", {"class": "dataBild"})
    for j in range(len(image)):
            names = image.find("img").get("title")
            name_list.append(''.join(names))
            name_list_def = name_list * len(injury_list)
```

Through the img tag I get the names of the players.
Do you have any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
player_inj_numb=[]

for url in (playerLinks):  
    player_name = url.split('/')[3]
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    print(response.status_code)
    injury_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(injury_data, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id="yw1")
    nbInjury = len(table.findAll("tr"))
    player_inj_numb.append((player_name,nbInjury-1))
    
print(player_inj_numb)
```

which outputs:

```
[('Serge Gnabry', 15), ('Jamal Musiala', 0), ('Douglas Costa', 15), ('Joshua Kimmich', 12), ('Alexander Nübel', 2), ('Kingsley Coman', 15), ('Christopher Scott', 0), ('Corentin Tolisso', 14), ('Leon Goretzka', 15), ('Javi Martínez', 15), ('Tiago Dantas', 0), ('Robert Lewandowski', 15), ('Lucas Hernández', 15), ('Josip Stanisic', 8), ('Thomas Müller', 13), ('Benjamin Pavard', 9), ('Bouna Sarr', 8), ('Leroy Sané', 11), ('Manuel Neuer', 15), ('David Alaba', 15), ('Niklas Süle', 13), ('Tanguy Nianzou', 4), ('Ron-Thorben Hoffmann', 4), ('Jérôme Boateng', 15), ('Alphonso Davies', 3), ('Eric Maxim Choupo-Moting', 15), ('Marc Roca', 7)]
```

I got the name from the url, since it is already there, no need for additional scraping.

The number of injurys is equal the number of row in the table minus the first row which is the table header.

Please note that some player have more than 15 injurys so you will need to get the subsequent page in those cases.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the mentioning of that I can get the player names out of the URL. I am also aware that not all pages are of similar lenghts and that I have to account for that. However, what I want in the end is a data frame that lists every injury (e.g. Serge Gnabry had 15 injuries

`
injury_list = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c" ]

`

for player X. in de end I want a dataframe like this: 

`
a playername

b playername

c playername